# What actions modify u-boot environment variables?

Tags: ubuntu, u-boot

**Update 2022-10-11**: Regarding the Adafruit Ultimate GPS HAT, in Ubuntu 22.04 LTS it works right out of the box on a Raspberry Pi 4. Maybe using Ubuntu 22.04 LTS on a Raspberry Pi 3 also has the same positive effect

---

In order to get an Adafruit Ultimate GPS HAT working on a Raspberry Pi 3 running Ubuntu 20.04 LTS I had to modify a u-boot environment variable.

The issue was that the GPS Hat is connected to the UART pins, making the Rapsberry Pi unbootable, so I used [this suggestion (How to disable ttyAMA0 console on boot (Raspberry Pi)?)](https://askubuntu.com/a/1278181/223999) so that u-boot stops listening for an abort signal.

Setting the u-boot variable bootdelay to -2 did the trick, now I can use the GPS Hat.

What I would like to know is what exactly could reset this bootdelay variable to the original value. If I upgrade from 20.04 to 22.04, would this overwrite the value? Or if I upgrade something via `apt`? How sure can I be that this won't break with some software upgrade, as I wouldn't be able to re-set that variable to -2 remotely, should some software change it?

Comment: *"The issue was that the GPS Hat is connected to the UART pins, making the Rapsberry Pi unbootable, so I used this suggestion"* -> That seems like a terrible example of an [XY problem](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/66378/212479) where the real problem is using u-boot instead of the normal Pi bootloader (which can be set via `/boot/cmdline.txt` to disable the serial console).  I'm sure you are aware of that and you have a significant concrete reason for using Ubuntu if this is what it requires (if there is no such reason, you should ditch it).

Comment: ...I mention that because while this is topical here, we have very few Ubuntu users (perhaps: for a significant and concrete reason ;\ )and **perhaps it would make more sense to ask on the Ubuntu forum which provided you with the original suggestion**.

Comment: @goldilocks, do you mean modify /boot/*firmware*/**cmdline.txt** to remove the line `console=serial0,115200` which is what `raspi-config` does when disabling the login console? If you refer to that, it didn't work. But since you are referring to **config.txt**, maybe you could leave a hint on what entry would be needed there?

Comment: Sorry, that should have been `cmdline.txt`, not `config.txt`, and the reason `raspi-config` might not have worked is that it isn't accounting for the non-standard mount location of the boot partition.  Presuming that it is still being applied in a uboot context (I don't know), find `/boot/firmware/cmdline.txt` and remove the `console=...` from there.  Be sure not to break the line (that file must be just one continuous line).

Comment: "non-standard mount location of the boot" I am aware of that. I created a dummy cmdline.txt and config.txt in /boot/ in order to see how raspi-config modifies these files. I applied these changes to the real files in /boot/firmware/ and the values I had to modify were the same which could be found in a lot of places on the internet. Modifying `/boot/firmware/cmdline.txt` as suggested definitely has no effect on the inability to boot. I also thought that this is strange, but setting uboot env appeared to be the only solution.

Comment: *"definitely has no effect I also thought that this is strange, but setting uboot env appeared to be the only solution."* -> This implies that uboot just by passes the normal boot sequence, which is so back assward is hard to believe a distro like Ubuntu would leave you with that.  You should try a directive that is dead simple to confirm, eg. `console=tty2` (instead of tty1, meaning the kernel's boot output will be on the second tty). If that is ineffective, me thinks you are really up a tree if the Ubuntu community has yet to provide some documentation about some alternative methodologies...

Comment: `console=tty2` sounds interesting. But now I wonder if I'm able to undo the `bootdelay -2` setting in order to test the `console=tty2` setting, since without the delay I may be unable to access the u-boot console via UART. I have ways to test it on another board, but not now. I'll update this once I know. Thanks.

Comment: So I managed to revert the bootdelay -2 env variable by renaming the file `/boot/firmware/uboot.env`. Without that file it uses the defaults and it is only created when an env-var is modified. In any case, `console=tty2` did not work, so I changed it back to the uboot variable. At this point I'm thinking that it isn't even picking up the contents of `/boot/firmware/cmdline.txt` during boot. How can I test this?

Comment: That was the point of `console=tty2`.  If that's being ignored, it's because `cmdline.txt` is not being used.  AFAIK, that's passed by the normal bootloader to the kernel, so you might want to investigate the uboot equivalent (again, I'm not a uboot user, but a quick seach-glance online for `uboot kernel command line` turns up some stuff).

Comment: If you do find a solution to this, please consider leaving an answer of your own.